# Create a 1D barcode and return asd base64 string in .NET6 where it works on all platforms

Tags: macos, .net-core, .net-6.0, barcode

I need to take a ticket id (only digits, but as a string), turn the string into a 1D barcode, then convert that to a image or bitmap or svg, then convert that into a base64 encoded string, where the base64 string can be returned as a response in a endpoint. It has be done in .NET6 and I'm doing it on a Mac (MacOS)

This is what I have so far (just put it in a console app for testing purposes):

```
using System.Drawing;
using BarcodeLib;

byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms,image.RawFormat);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

var ticketId = "038000356216";
Barcode b = new Barcode();
Image img = b.Encode(TYPE.UPCA, ticketId, Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 120);
var barcodeAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageToByteArray(img));
Console.WriteLine(barcodeAsString);
```

This does work because the Barcodelib uses Windows specific API's, which then causes a exception on the Mac. This code would properly work on a Windows machine. But since I'm on a Mac this is the the issue that I would like your help with.

How can I do this in a "platform neutral" way - something that will work on both MacOS and Windows?
I'm open for using any open source library/Nuget package that supports this - just as long as I don't have to pay for it, or there is going to be a waterwark on the image.

I have tried several libraries / Nuget packages - all with the same result as in the example.